# postgresql, key is not present in table error, but key present in the table

Tags: postgresql, doctrine-orm

I have tables `providers`, and `provider_groups`.

`providers`:

```
create table providers
(
    id integer not null constraint providers_pkey primary key,
    available         boolean not null,
);
```

and `provider_groups`

```
create table provider_groups
(
    id integer  not null provider_groups_pkey primary key,
    provider_id integer not null constraint fk_237d25c5d3e1ebb8
            references providers on delete cascade,
    type              varchar(100) not null
);


create index idx_237d25c5d3e1ebb8
    on provider_groups (provider_id);
```

and my application (which using of doctrine ORM) trying to update data for some provider and his related group. I'm sure both provider and group exists in database, but for some reason it's failing with error

```
  SQLSTATE[23503]: Foreign key violation: 7 ERROR:  insert or update on table "provider_groups" violates foreign key constraint "fk_237d25c5d3e1ebb8"\n
    DETAIL:  Key (provider_id)=(28007) is not present in table "providers".
```

but as I mentioned it's there, I can see it through database UI.

What I'm doing wrong??? Can it be related to some cache on DB side, as it's a pretty old logic running for a while and that error apears only now... Thanks in advice!

Comment: `references roviders on delete cascade,` copy and paste error? The error is telling you that  the value `28007` is not present in  the `providers.id` column. Try `select * from providers where id = 28007`.

Comment: Do you happen to have two tables for providers, namely `providers` and `roviders`? There's `references roviders` in your second `create table` statement.

Comment: @haba713, I'm guessing that is copy/paste error otherwise the SQL error would have been: `... is not present in table "roviders"`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver, I see. That's true.

Comment: sorry `roviders` it's a typo, it should be everywhere `providers`. and yeah, as I told I can see `provider` with id 28007, from database UI, and by running `elect * from providers where id = 28007`

Comment: Are there `provider` tables in more then one schema? In `psql` do `\dt *.providers` to see. If that is the case then the `search_path` is set such that the wrong table is being looked up. Best way to correct is to schema qualify the table name.

Comment: Another thought, try a `REINDEX` on `providers`.